# How do I add a "noHigherStocks" function when there are no higher stocks in a list?

Tags: python-3.x

I am attempting to create a program that has 4 functions, getStocks, searchStocks, printStocks, and then the main function that uses the other three.
My issue is that I want to make it so that if the stock you searched for is the highest stock, I want the message "There are no higher stocks" to appear as the output instead of empty space, but I am unsure what and where I would need to add to do that. I have the "noHigherStocks" variable as the message I want displayed, but where am I to implement it? I feel as though I should use an else statement in the main function, but I can't think of where it would make sense to put it. Thanks for reading! any help or tips would be greatly appreciated :-)

```
def getStocks():
    stockNames = []
    stockPrices = []
    name = str(input("What is the name of the stock?"))
    price = int(input("what is the price of that stock?"))
    while name != 'done':
        stockNames.append(name)
        stockPrices.append(price)
        name = str(input("What is the name of the stock?"))
        if name != 'done':
            price = int(input("what is the price of that stock?"))

    return (stockNames, stockPrices)


# returns a single value pertaining to the found price      
def searchStocks(stockNames, stockPrices, s):
    for i in range (len(stockNames)):
        if stockNames[i] == s:
            return stockPrices[i]
    return -1

# print the names of stocks whose price is higher than p.
def printStock(stockNames, stockPrices, p):
    i = 0
    while i <len(stockPrices):
        if p < stockPrices[i]:
            print(stockNames[i])
        i = i + 1
    return



def main():
    n,p = getStocks()
    stock = str(input("what stock are you searching for?"))
    price = searchStocks(n,p,stock)
    printStock(n,p,price)
    noStocksHigher = str('There are no stocks higher than',stock)

main()
```

Comment: I think the change has to be in the "printStock" function, as an else statement, but everytime i try to change it i get "invalid syntax"

Answer (score 0):

*This might be solved using the max() builtin.  Since you already know the price of the stock for which you searched, you could just compare that price against the highest price in p, and if equal, print your message, otherwise search the list.*

Starting where you call searchStocks:

```
price = searchStocks(n,p,stock)

if max(p) == price:

    print('There are no stocks higher than',stock)
else:

    printStock(n,p,price)
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the formatting help.  I am pretty new to this editor and it wasn't behaving as I would have expected.  I appreciate the assistance.